# React inner div height 100%

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

[image]Hi all I am new in react and stuck on one issue

Issue:- My application have lot of div like "root","component" and component UI div's when I set my component UI div height which is nested div to 100% without touching css of upper div also without adding 100% height in all upper div rather than "body" what I am excepting in this that my component UI (nested) div grab height of full screen

Hope guys you understand my issue please help me in issue

In this picture _logincard not grabbing whole height

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: @vijayst I updated   my question with one photo which tell everything about my problem

Answer (score 19):

This is not react issue but a css one! This is how it works!

When you say `height:100%` it is calculated using parents height! If parent don't have a specific height browser cannot determine child's height in percentage!

On solution you can use is css3 vuewport unit, `vh`

```
div{ height:100vh; }
```

This will make your div to take 100 percent height of screen without changing any parent properties! Viewport unit wirk with respect to screen height, where 100vh = 100% screen height!

Comment: Ok but If I have one div1 which height is 75vh  and also have another div2 which  is inside in div1 not exactly after div1>div2 It may be like this div1>..div..>div2  I need div2 grabe all height from div1

Comment: Not possible with css, parent need specific height or give height to that child div same as desired parent height, i.e. 75vh! But if you ever changed that height you have to change both! (If design allows, you can just give height to child i.e. 75vh, all wrapper div will grow in size as per child)

Comment: // upper div
 ._card {
        width: 65vh;
        height: 75vh;
        background: orange;
        position: absolute;
        left: 17.5vh;
        top: 12.5vh;
    }
//nested div
    ._loginLeft {
        height: 75vh;
        background-color: orange;
    }
_loginLeft is inside the card I do not want 75vh in .loginleft It is depends upone upper div height can you suggest me something rather than 75vh in .loginleft

Answer (score 1):

This is not a React issue. This is how css works. If a parent container does not have a specified height, you cannot use % to calculate the dimensions of a child element. You will need to explicitly set the height of the containers up to the body element.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing

```
div{ height:100vh; }
```

When you put vh = viewport unit, 100 = 100% of the screen